# UITableViewCell as Header or Footer View

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview

I know about UITableView reusable header and footer view

but in my case, i have UITableView Cells, which i need to place also in section headers and also in normal rows

if i use

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    MyCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    // ...
    return cell;
}
```

**How does it work out with the reusing? (is the message to be available for reuse even than passed), or does this disable the cell reuse**

Comment: You can't use that there. There is a method for your need. Read the docs maybe?

Comment: You can use that there. Unusual, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

The cells get dealloc'ed when they go off-screen. So they don't get reused. An easy way to verify this is to subclass `UITableViewCell` with the following

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"I got dealloc'ed");
}
```

and observe the console output as you scroll.

Answer (score 0):

These has always worked fine. You first should create a prototype with that name, or register a custom nib with your custom section identifier. HOWEVER , I noticed this breaks in iOS 7 when you add new sections to the table dynamically. Reverting to a plain non-reusing UIView works. Really a shame!